# How to install scikit-multilearn using Conda

Tags: python, conda, scikit-multilearn

To install scikit-multilearn, I have tried the following commands with no luck:

```
conda install scikit-multilearn
```

or,

```
conda install -c condo-forge scikit-multilearn
```

The [official website](http://scikit.ml) of scikit-multilearn propose using pip:

```
pip install scikit-multilearn
```

How should I install a python package when I don't find it on Anaconda repository? Would it be OK if I use pip occasionally, while my default package manager is conda?

Comment: In general, you should use conda whenever possible, even from a different channel (especially a well-supported channel like conda-forge). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45919845/2449192 for one reason one (disclaimer, that's my answer)

Answer (score 4):

It's fine for you to use pip along with conda. It's made to work this way. You have to be aware that not every package is on conda but only on pip. If you do `conda env export > environment.yml`, you will see that there is a mix of conda packages and pip.

Comment: Re: "It's made to work this way" -> Not necessarily, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45919845/2449192 (disclaimer, that's my answer)

Comment: @darthbith the sentence was just to indicate that pip is also able to work along with conda but you're right with your remark:)

Answer (score 4):

I eventually installed scikit-multilearn using pip:

```
pip install scikit-multilearn
```

However, I got the following import error while trying to import it:

> ImportError: No module named builtins

To solve this, I upgraded the future package:

`$pip install future --upgrade`

Then, I successfully imported scikit-multilearn.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned command

> > conda install scikit-multilearn

is correct and has a successful result, if Anaconda has already installed.

Comment: I had Anaconda installed and updated. But as I mentioned above, I eventually had to upgrade the future package. I'm not really sure why it was needed.

Comment: skmultilearn is not available on condo yet. See @Edwin above answer which work well.

Answer (score 2):

You can effectively install `scikit-multilearn` in a Conda environment using PIP doing this

```
import sys

! {sys.executable} -m pip install scikit-multilearn

! {sys.executable} -m pip install liac-arff
```

I installed and tested it in a Jupyter Notebook by Anaconda

Comment: This helped me. Thanks

Comment: I can't edit the comment right now, but please be aware that arff is the wrong package and skmultilearn needs liac-arff.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I install a python package when I don't find it on Anaconda repository?

```
pip install <package-name>
```

> Would it be OK if I use pip occasionally, while my default package manager is conda?

Yes, it is totally fine. When you use import, the package will be found irrespective of the means of installation; conda or pip.

If you want to install a package for future use, or for more than a single project, you might want to install it into the root environment. This will allow you to import the package any time.
If you are using it for a specific project, and probably just once, create a new virtual environment, install the required packages in that environment and run your code within it.

Creating a virtual environment: [Link](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)