# What is the effect of using pip to install python packages on anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have installed a fresh anaconda v4.4. I realized that python packages can be installed using both conda and pip. What is the effect of using pip to install python packages instead of conda when using anaconda? Will the pip-installed libraries cease to function? I am using python v3

EDIT: I don't think the question is a duplicate of [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)
That question explains the difference between pip and conda but does not talk about the effect of using pip when conda can be used.

Comment: this could be a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Comment: Honestly, the duplicate covers a subset of this question, and at any rate is not as immediately interpretable for the specific query. I think this question (and the accepted answer below) stands for itself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything *might* keep working if you use `pip` to install vs `conda`. However, Conda cannot manage dependencies that `pip` has installed - it cannot upgrade them, or remove them. More importantly, conda will install a package **even if its already been installed with `pip`**! Try this test:

```
conda create -n testenv python=3
conda activate testenv
pip install numpy
conda install scipy
```

You will see from the third command that conda will want to re-install NumPy, even though it has already been installed with `pip`. This can cause problems if there are C libraries whose linking is different, or something like that. In general, whenever possible, use conda to install packages into conda environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If both conda and pip packages are installed, is it correct that the conda package will be used by default?

Comment: I don't think that would necessarily be the case... it will depend (for instance, in the case of C libraries) on how the link resolver works, which may be platform dependent

Comment: Can I get a source for your info?

Comment: A source for what info? You can try the code here and see for yourself.