# Creating conda env using packages from pip - PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a conda environment with a couple of packages that I have installed but it throws:
`PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels`

important note: the packages that come back with above error are the ones that are installed using `pip`. so the question can be put as:

**How to create a conda environment composed of packages that are installed using `pip`?**

To be clear, packages are installed using conda pip at `~/anaconda3/bin/pip`

`conda create --name myenvname scipy parquet`

```
Fetching package metadata .........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - parquet

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

`conda list | grep parquet`

```
fastparquet               0.0.6                     <pip>
parquet                   1.2                       <pip>
```

`conda list | grep scipy`

`scipy                     0.19.0              np112py36_0`

Comment: I would suggest to use the `fastparquet` conda package from the conda-forge channel. If you really want to use pip to install a package when you create an environment, you can use the file input option.

Comment: @darthbith you can view the `parquet` package as an example here. I'm mainly wondering about bringing packages that are available in `pip` but not on `conda` channels and being being able to add them to an environment. I understand that I can go ahead and convert any module into `conda` compatible form and make it available on a channel but I think there are more streamlined ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @darthbith with file input option, I'm not sure what you are exactly referring to? are you referring to adding configs directly yml file to create the env?

Comment: I would recommend to use conda to install every package that you can, particularly if it includes a C library. The reason is that conda cannot manage pip-installed packages, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45919845/2449192 Regarding the file input option, I mean this: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file You can specify pip packages in that environment.yml file and they will be included when you create the environment