# conda install does not seem to have acces to latest package version

Tags: python, pip, keras, anaconda

when i install keras on my conda environement it does not seem to install the latest version since i have 2.0.5 and itseems to be 2.0.8 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras)

when i run `conda update keras` i get the following error message :

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda2/envs/conda_env:
#
keras                     2.0.5                    py36_0
```

same problem when i try to install keras-vis but then it does not exist at all so i have to do a pip-install that create double packages in my environement

Comment: Have you tried `conda update anaconda`?

Comment: For keras-vis on Ubuntu you can download the repo (or clone), cd into it with bash and run
 sudo ipython setup.py install
It worked for me since my ipython is on conda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conda uses it's own [repository](https://anaconda.org/search?q=keras) of compiled binaries. The latest version available in the main channel "anaconda" is keras 2.0.5. If you use conda-forge you get access to 2.0.6.

Newer versions need to be installed over pip.

EDIT:

You can actually use [this channel](https://anaconda.org/jaikumarm/keras) to get the newer version.

Comment: +1 good answer! However, one should not use pip to install packages into Conda environments. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45919845/2449192