# Distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, msgpack

I'm having a problem trying to install plotly. I proceeded to upgrade anaconda using the command line on Debian 9 and I received the error message "distributed 1.21.0 requires msgpack, which is not installed".

Then I tried a `conda install mspack`, then a `pip install --upgade plotly`, and I get "distributed 1.22.0 requires msgpack, which is not installed". This 1.22.0 error message is what kicked off my whole upgrading process of many packages. Does this break plotly? Don't know, haven't tried but judging from msgpack website https://msgpack.org/, it is probable to cause errors. We'll see, I guess. Not sure what else to do.

`pip install msgpack` does not fix the problem

Answer (score 50):

I face same issue while installing dask Later I resolved it using either of these two methods.

First Method: Run this command

```
conda install -c anaconda msgpack-python
```

Second Method: Run this command

```
pip install msgpack
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that pip wont work in anaconda. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917541/what-is-the-effect-of-using-pip-to-install-python-packages-on-anaconda/45919845#45919845

Answer (score 11):

For Windows users who have stumbled upon this thread:

Run Anaconda Prompt as Administrator and enter the following:

```
pip install msgpack
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your multiple questions

1. "distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack" This error has nothing to do with plotly installation. Its due to the way anaconda is installed
2. The error will not affect installation/upgrades of any of the packages.
3. "pip install msgpack does not fix the problem" .It will not fix until you try to install msgpack with user admin(Windows) / root(linux) right.
   I got this fixed on my Windows 10 & Lubuntu 16 with above mentioned solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to installing msgpack in your work/office machine where PIP install have proxy issues. you can try below method.

Download msgpack using below link : https://pypi.org/project/msgpack-python/#files
Extract the .tar.gz file
Navigate till setup.py file in command prompt
Execute `python setup.py install` command to install

Answer (score 0):

I installed the `TextBlob` package for text classification. Right after that I tried to open Jupyter Notebook and got this error message : `AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'`
I was searching for a solution to above problem and stumbled upon a solution regarding uninstalling `tornado` and downgrading it to `tornado 4.5.3` . I did that and it did not solve the problem. Then I realized this warning `distributed 1.22.0 requires msgpack, which is not installed.` After installing `msgpack` the problem is solved.